# Boolean logic to query tags?

Tags: finder, finder-tag

I want to search for files that have certain tags, and don't have other tags. Right now, when I use finder I can list the tags I want (e.g. searching for files that have tag1 AND tag2 AND tag) but I don't know how to query for for files that e.g. have tag1 AND NOT tag2. Is there currently a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Start a new find (command-f).
- Under the main "Search" heading select the first pop-up and select "Other..." From the list of search terms, select "Tags".
- In the second pop-up select "contains", and in the next field, enter a term. e.g. "Orange".
- Over to the right, click the "+" button to search an additional term. In the new first pop-up, select "Tags". Select "is not" from the second pop-up, and enter the term e.g. "red".

This will select all files tagged "Orange", but not files tagged "Orange" and "Red"